# Does isomorphism between normed space implies equivalence of norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a vector space, $\|\cdot\|_1,\|\cdot\|_2$ be two norms on $E$, if $T:(E,\|\cdot\|_1)\to (E,\|\cdot\|_2)$ be an isomorphism (linear bijection, $T,T^{-1}$ are bouned), then does this imply these two norms are equivalent, i.e. $$\exists \alpha,\beta>0, \forall x\in E,  \alpha\|x\|_1\le\|x\|_2\le\beta \|x\|_1$$

I know $\|x\|_2= \|T^{-1}Tx\|_2$ but I don't think I can proceed, since we only have $\|T^{-1}x\|_1\le\|T^{-1}\| \|x\|_2$. The problem is that I don't know how to connect $\|x\|_2$ with $\|x\|_1$

I know it's true for particular maps, say identity map, but is it true in general?

Or, does it implies a weaker condition, that is, for any $x_n,x\in E$, 
$$x_n \overset{\|\cdot\|_1}{\rightarrow}x\implies x_n \overset{\|\cdot\|_2}{\rightarrow}x,\text{ and },x_n \overset{\|\cdot\|_2}{\rightarrow}x\implies x_n \overset{\|\cdot\|_1}{\rightarrow}x$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, then identity isn't bounded. One can take the set of finite sequences and complete them under non-equivalent Hilbert norms, e.g. $\sum n^2|x_k|^2$, $\sum |x_k|^2$. Then $x_n\mapsto n x_n$ will give a bijection isometry. This won't do for a Banach space though, I wonder if there's an example of two non-equivalent norms that give the same completion.

Comment: @MichaelHardy May I know are you claiming identity map is always bounded and has bounded inverse? I don't think it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to prove that the norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|T\cdot\|_2$ are equivalent.

Equivalence of $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ does not hold in general.
For instance, let $X$ be the space of sequences with finite support equipped with the $l^\infty$ norm.

Define $T$ by
$$
Tx = (x_1, \frac{x_2}2, \frac{x_3}3, \dots).
$$
Define $\|x\|_1:=\|x\|_{l^\infty}$, 
$$
\|x\|_2 := \sup_{n} |nx_n|.
$$
Then $T$ is bounded from $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)\to(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$. In fact $\|Tx\|_2=\|x\|_1$. This implies that $T^{-1}$ is bounded, too.

However, the norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are not equivalent. To see this, take the unit sequence $e_n$ (zero except for the $n$-th position, which is one):
$$
\|e_n\|_1 = 1, \quad \|e_n\|_2 = n.
$$
Moreover,
$$
\|Te_n\|_2 = 1, \quad \|Te_n\|_1\to0.
$$
This example essentially  uses the non-completeness of $X$. I wonder if it is possible to construct a counter-example with complete space.

Comment: For the Banach case : take a Banach $(X,\|.\|_1)$, $f : X \rightarrow X$ bijective non continious and define $\|x\|_2:=\|f(x)\|_1$. Then $f : (X,\|.\|_2) \rightarrow (X,\|.\|_1)$ is an isomorphism of Banach spaces, but the two norms are non-equivalent. This requires Axiom of Choice, because we don't know how to construct non-continuous endomorphism on Banach spaces.