# Do equivalent norms give isomorphic normed spaces and conversely

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Two normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ are said to be isomorphic if there exists a bijective linear mapping from $X$ to $Y$ such that $||Tx||=||x||$ forall $x\in X$

> - Let $X_1=(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ and $X_2=(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ be two normed spaces such that the norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are equivalent .Are the two normed spaces isomorphic?

Since $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are equivalent so there exists constants $a,b\neq0$ such that $a\|x\|_1\le \|x\|_2\le b\|x\|_1\forall x\in X$.

I am unable to find a map .I took the identity map which is bijective. But we need to show $\|\cdot\|_1=\|\cdot\|_2$ which is false.

> - Let $X_1=(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ and $X_2=(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ be two normed spaces such that the two normed spaces are isomorphic.Are the norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are equivalent ?

Here we can find $T:X_1\to X_2$ such that $\|Tx\|_2=\|x\|_1$. But how to find the two non-negative constants from here?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can someone help please?

Comment: You say isometric in the title, but isomorphic in the question. Which is it?

Comment: Edited @HaraldHanche-Olsen

Comment: You seem to be working from the wrong definition of isomorphic. In your first question, you say you need to show $\|\cdot\|_1=\|\cdot\|_2$, but that is the requirement for an isometry. Similarly, in your second question, the stated equality says that $T$ is an isometry. So I guess I have to ask again, whether you really mean isomorphic or isometric.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I have done the edits;you may look it now;Maybe that definition may not match yours but this is what I have to say

Comment: For your second question you might check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143042/does-isomorphism-between-normed-space-implies-equivalence-of-norm

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: It seems that OP is working in the category of normed spaces with linear contractions as morphisms. In this category the iso-morphisms are the isometric ones.